# Regular Expression in JavaScript with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to remove in javascript from my text_string all characters that are not letters (in all languages) and numbers. I can do it individually. But how can I put both in ONE expression, so that both conditions are true at the same time?

```
var text_string = '!#Ab+Z1_↕.2ü翻訳';
text_string = text_string.replace(/\P{Letter}/gu, ''); 
text_string = text_string.replace(/\P{Number}/gu, ''); 
text_string = text_string.replace(/[^#]/, ''); 
// should be replaced to  #AbZ12ü翻訳
```

Comment: If I understand:   `text_string.replace(/[^(a-zA-Z0-9#)]/g, '');`

Comment: No. That does not work with foreign languages without latin characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in unicode for search:

```bash
[^\p{Letter}\p{Number}#]+
```

and replace with empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ndQb4x/1)

**Code:**

```js
const regex = /[^\p{Letter}\p{Number}#]+/gu;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('[^\\p{Letter}\\p{Number}#]+', 'gu')

const str = `!#Ab+Z1_↕.2ü翻訳`;

const result = str.replace(regex, '');

console.log(result);
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `[^\p{Letter}\p{Number}#]+`: In a character class match any character that is not `#` not a unicode letter and not a unicode number.

Remember that `\p{something}` is inverse of `\P{something}`

Comment: What would it be if we had an additional requirement that the hash mark is only allowed in position 1. At all other positions the hash mark  should be replaced as well.

Comment: That would be: `[^\p{Letter}\p{Number}#]+|(?<!^)#`